# Laravel 5 File Facade not execute next code if statement false

Tags: php, laravel-5, file-exists

with this code if file exist it will give me error

> ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 338: mkdir(): File exists

instead of execute next code which will insert user table

```
.....
if(!File::exists($path.$data['avatar']->getClientOriginalName())){
    File::makeDirectory($path, 0755, true);
    Image::make($data['avatar']->getRealPath())->resize(200, 200)->save($path.$data['avatar']->getClientOriginalName());
    Post::create([
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'content' => "assets/uploads".date('/Y/m/d/').$data['avatar']->getClientOriginalName(),
            'type'    => 'image'
        ]);
}
$user = new User;
$user->username = $data['username'];
$user->password = Hash::make($data['password']);
$user->avatar   = "assets/uploads".date('/Y/m/d/').$data['avatar']->getClientOriginalName();
$user->email = $data['email'];
$user->first_name = $data['first_name'];
$user->last_name = $data['last_name'];
$user->role_id = $data['level'];
$user->save();
....
```

AFAIK the above code should execute insert if statement true or false, should i use `else` statement? if so then I must repeat insert user twice and it's bad.

So, the question is why the above code return error instead of execute next code? and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm sure the problem is with the path you have are giving in the if statement, please double check it once. echo it out somewhere and check. You might be using some unwanted path in there.

Comment: @ParthapratimNeog ahhh.. thank missing some logic before create directory, see my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Missing some logic before create directory, here is my explanation

This code will check if **path to filename** doesn't exists then do something.

```
!File::exists($path.$data['avatar']->getClientOriginalName()
```

And the error break at the below code.

```
File::makeDirectory($path, 0755, true);
```

Question 1

> should i use else statement? if so then I must repeat insert user
>   twice and it's bad.

**No at all**, you just missing some logic before create directory.

Question 2

> why the above code return error instead of execute next code? and how
>   to fix it?

Are you kidding me **path to filename** doesn't exists don't mean **path** doesn't exist, it can be just **filename** doesn't exists, so please make sure if your **path** doesn't exist then create the folder, anyway with your case **filename** doesn't exist but the **path** is exist but you call `File::makeDirectory()` then that's why you will end with

> ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 338: mkdir(): File exists

Here is a fix, sync your code with this.

```
...
if(!File::exists($path)){
    File::makeDirectory($path, 0755, true);
}
...
```